# Laravel cast json to array

Tags: collections, laravel-8, laravel-9

The `client` attribute is a json filed in the database, which I caste as array in my model. However by retuning the Model to an array, the `client` attribute remains as json string:

```php
$provider = TokenCacheProvider::all([
    'name', 'auth_url', 'token_url', 'auth_endpoint', 'client'
])
    ->keyBy('name')
    ->toArray();
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => azure_ad
    [auth_url] => /oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    [token_url] => /oauth2/v2.0/token
    [auth_endpoint] => https://login.microsoftonline.com/
    [client] => {"tenant":"some value","client_id":"some value","client_secret":"some value"}
)
```

I would expect and output like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => azure_ad
    [auth_url] => /oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    [token_url] => /oauth2/v2.0/token
    [auth_endpoint] => https://login.microsoftonline.com/
    [client] => Array
        (
            [tenant] => 'some value'
            [client_id] => 'some value'
            [client_secret] => 'some value'
            [scope] => 'some value'
        )
)
```

My Model has the corresponding `$casts`:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'client' => 'array',
];
```

### Edit

This comes a little bit closer to what I need, but it returns only the `clients` attribute ‍

```php
$provider = TokenCacheProvider::all([
    'name', 'auth_url', 'token_url', 'auth_endpoint', 'client'
])
    ->keyBy('name')
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return json_decode($item->client);
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

```php
$provider = TokenCacheProvider::all([
    'name', 'auth_url', 'token_url', 'auth_endpoint', 'client'
])
    ->keyBy('name')
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return collect([
            'auth_url' =>$item->auth_url,
            'token_url' =>$item->token_url,
            'auth_endpoint' =>$item->auth_endpoint,
            'client' =>json_decode($item->client,true)
        ]);
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Not sure if this is the most beautiful solution but it does exactly what I want.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [auth_url] => /oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    [token_url] => /oauth2/v2.0/token
    [auth_endpoint] => https://login.microsoftonline.com/
    [client] => Array
        (
            [tenant] => some values
            [client_id] => some values
            [client_secret] => some values
            [scope] => https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
        )

)
```

Feedback and enhancements are highly welcome!

Cheers